# Airflow via docker-compose keeps trying to access sqlite although postgres configured

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I try to set up a Dockerized airflow instance, but whatever I do (so far..) it keeps trying to access some sqlite3 database where I do not know where the instruction comes from. I point to the Postgres instance everywhere (deemed) possible through `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN`, and even `AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB`.

A typical error message when starting up is like:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: job
```

Full docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: apache/airflow:2.0.0
  environment:
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
    - AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=FB0o_zt4e3Ziq3LdUUO7F2Z95cvFFx16hU8jTeR1ASM=
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=True
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
  volumes:
    - /home/x/docker/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - /home/x/docker/airflow/airflow-data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - /home/x/docker/airflow/airflow-data/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - /home/x/docker/airflow/airflow-data/airflow.cfg:/opt/airlfow/airflow.cfg
  depends_on:
    - db

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    #image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PORT=9501
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - 9501:9501
    command:
      - -p 9501

  airflow-init:
    << : *airflow-common
    container_name: airflow_init
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    environment:
      - SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
    command:
      - -c
      - airflow users list || ( airflow db init &&
        airflow users create
          --role Admin
          --username airflow
          --password airflow
          --email airflow@airflow.com
          --firstname airflow
          --lastname airflow )
    restart: on-failure

  airflow-webserver:
    << : *airflow-common
    command: airflow webserver
    ports:
      - 9500:8080
    container_name: airflow_webserver
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW_USERNAME=airflow
      - AIRFLOW_PASSWORD=airflow
      - SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    << : *airflow-common
    command: airflow scheduler
    container_name: airflow_scheduler
    environment:
      - SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
      - AIRFLOW_CONN_METADATA_DB=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:9501/airflow
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by following this docker-compose.yaml file:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/apache-airflow/start/docker-compose.yaml

And instead of trying to tweak the ports of postgres (and redis) used the "expose" option, which avoids conflicts with other containers on the same host.

So **not**:

```
 environment: 
   POSTGRES_PORT: 9501
 ports:
   - 9501:9501
```

**But**: run it (internally) with the default ports and do not try to share them external:

```
 expose: 
   - 5432
```

Still not sure what was the problem with using the higher ports. It may be some default fallback to sqlite when the configured DB for some reason cannot be connected.